# How to show data from cursor into a listview

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I'm new to android and I'm stuck in a problem.
This is my main class and simply inserting the data and showing the data in Logcat. I want to show the data in ListView in a new activity. Now I am not getting how to get data from cursor and show it on ListView . I have made a `view.xml` & `view.java` to show data but I don't know how to show data on that activity. Should I make an adapter class, cursoradapter or flater, etc. (I want to know the next steps).

Thanks in advance :)

**Main Class**

```
  public class main extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        addListenerOnButton();
        database_delete();
        database_add();

    }



    public void database_add() {

     try{
        Database_handler db = new Database_handler(this);

        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");

       db.addData(new get_set(131,"A-Lucy")) ;
       db.addData(new get_set(132,"A-kk")) ;
       db.addData(new get_set(133,"A_Tweety")) ;
       db.addData(new get_set(134,"A-Naruto")) ;
       Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");


    List<get_set> getSetList = db.getalldata();
        for(get_set set : getSetList){
            String log = "CODEE: " + set.getCode()  + ", Description: " + set.getDescr();
            Log.d("CODE: ", log);
        }
```

here is some code of my database handler class having functionality of inserting,retrieving data.

**Database handler class**

```
public class Database_handler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

 private static final int DATABASE_Version = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_Name = "android_db";
private static final String TABLE_Name = "all_data";

private static final String Column_Name_code = "code";
private static final String Column_name_desc = "description";
private SQLiteDatabase db;

Database_handler(Context cont){
    super(cont,DATABASE_Name,null,DATABASE_Version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CREATE_TABLE_ANDRO = " CREATE TABLE " +  TABLE_Name + "(" + Column_Name_code + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , "
            + Column_name_desc + " TEXT )";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ANDRO);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int Older_version, int new_version) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_Name );
    onCreate(db);
}
//    Inserting record
    public void addData (get_set getSet){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        ContentValues cv =   new ContentValues();
        cv.put (Column_Name_code, getSet.getCode());
        cv.put(Column_name_desc, getSet.getDescr());
        db.insert(TABLE_Name,null,cv);
        db.close();
    }

     Retrieving data
    public List<get_set> getalldata(){
         List<get_set> data_list = new ArrayList<get_set>();

         String select_query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_Name;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(select_query,null);

        if (cur.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                get_set getsetObj = new get_set();
                getsetObj.setCode(Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(0)));
                getsetObj.setDescr(cur.getString(1));
                data_list.add(getsetObj);
            }  while (cur.moveToNext());
        }
        return data_list;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the database_add() function, after insertion of data into the database, Call an intent to the next Activity. In that new activity, call getalldata() function. AS you are already getting returned by a list, use Array adapter List view, with String type of an ArrayList, by following the below tutorial. It will work like a charm.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

And also, I'd suggest you to include db.getalldata() function inside AsyncTask, because you dont want heavy database transactions in the main thread.